# What is the cost of sending a small payload to space?

Tags: rockets, model-rocketry

What is the typical weight of the propellant required to send a tiny armature rocket into orbit? What is the cost of such a small rocket in today's dollars?

Comment: This depends on the actual mass of the payload, as well as the kind of orbit you want to attain.

Comment: Also note that the mass of the propellant is only a minor part of the cost.

Comment: There are no amateur rockets that can reach orbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this NASA-Kennedy paper](http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/nexgen/Nexgen_Downloads/AIAA_JPC_Paper_Review_Measure_Space_Trans_Afford_r8.pdf), this plot shows actual launch costs in $/kg for various payload sizes for payloads sent to low-earth orbit (LEO):

[image]

This plot is consistent with the NASA-Marshall's [website](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/news/background/facts/astp.html) which states: "Today, it costs $10,000 to put a pound of payload in Earth orbit."

Typically, getting a payload to geosynchronous orbit costs three times as much as getting it to LEO.

Recently, start-up space companies have been promising much lower costs.  For example, SpaceX is talking about [breaking the \$1000 per pound ($2,200/kg) Launch Cost Barrier](http://www.buildtheenterprise.org/spacex-breaking-the-1000-per-pound-launch-cost-barrier).

As for how much a "small" payload costs, as you can see in the above plot, rockets have economies of scale: the larger payloads typically have lower per kg costs.  For low cost, your best bet may be to 'hitchhike' on a larger payload.